# How to show a list on mouse click using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#cssdropdown li.headlink').hover(
                function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'block'); },
                function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'none'); });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="cssdropdown">
        <li class="headlink">
            <a href="http://google.com/">Search Engines</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://live.com/">Live Search</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="headlink">
            <a href="http://shopping.com">Shopping</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://amazon.com/">Amazon</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://ebay.com/">eBay</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://craigslist.com/">CraigsList</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I can show a list on mouse over.

I want to show the lists on mouse click instead.
For instance, if I click on `Search Engines`, the `Google, Yahoo and Live Search list` will happear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("UL UL").css("display", "none");

$(".title").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   $(this).next("UL").toggle();
});
```

I've added a class of `title` to each of your clickable items so that the code can be reused.

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/9udaU/)

Comment: thanks Rory, it's that. Is it possible to shrink the other list (if opened) when I open the first one?

Comment: humm, but it's possible to shrink the, for instance, the second list (if opened) when I open the first one (and vice-versa)?

Comment: @aF. Do you mean something like [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)?

Comment: @Fatal omg that's beautiful, it's exactly that what I'm looking :)

Comment: @aF. Glad to help, sounded like you want sth. like this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just give an id to the `<a>` tag and make an event for that. like this: `$('#search_engines').click(function () { });`

Answer (score 0):

This should give the behaviour you want, any open list will be hidden and the appropriate list opened:

```
  $('li.headlink ul').hide();

  $('li.headlink > a').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('li.headlink ul').hide();
     $(this).next().show();
  });
```

or using the toggle approach so you can close all lists:

```
$('li.headlink ul').hide();

$('li.headlink > a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var thisList = $(this).next();
      thisList .toggle();
      $('li.headlink ul').not(thisList).hide();
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AcksR/) showing the second approach working