# How do I make a list which only appears when a <button> is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button

I'm trying to make a button which when clicked, makes a list appear/disappear.

How would I go about linking the two?

Would Javascript be the best option for this, or can this be achieved with CSS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180842/how-to-show-a-list-on-mouse-click-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand, maka div with all the contents that you need to show on click. then write on click function for the button and use show() or toggle function to show the div.

```
$( "#buttonid" ).click(function() {
$('#divtoshow').show();
});
```

instead of show() you can use toggle() also.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) will help you here.

You can use the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event along with [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery it is very simple.

```
$("#buttonID").on('click',function(){
$("listID").toggleClass("contentVisibulity");

});
```

**css**

```
.contentVisibulity{
display:none;
}
```

[Jquery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)